# Update values in dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, riot.js

I am new to Riot JS and a little stuck I have two dropdown one which contains some sizes and the other which gets populated with quantity based on size selected.

When first changing the sizes it works fine, it is on subsequent changes that it does not update correct and there are values which should be there. So for size 8 it should only ever show 1,2,3 but after the multiple changes there are other sizes shown.

I have created a JSFiddle to show what is happening.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/03fd0v6z/

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I have just found that there is a bug which doesn't update the array in the latest version of the library.

Comment: Hehe, I was wondering about the same bug yesterday. Since Version 2.0.14 it is fixed again.